# How to resize VLC window?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm running VLC 2.0.6 on Windows 7. The application launches by running in full screen mode, and I'm unable to resize.

My <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Video Settings are as follows:

- Display > Fullscreen is unchecked.
- Always on top is unchecked

How can I configure VLC to allow me to re-size and move window to different positions on my monitor?

Comment: Try typing Alt-Enter while it's running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>F11</kbd> will toggle the window between full screen and windowed view.

If VLC is defaulting to open in full screen, you can change that in Windows 7 by

1. Open VLC.
2. Resize the window to the desired default size (if you are in full screen, switch to window view first).
3. Close out of VLC.

Now the next time you open VLC it should open in the view you last left it.

Comment: I was viewing VLC on secondary monitor in a dual monitor setup. Once I moved to primary monitor F11 worked.

Answer (score 9):

You can use shortcuts to re-size to various preset values:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> Quarter size
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> Half size
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> Original size
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> Double size

You can change the shortcuts by going to Tools>Preferences>Hotkeys

Comment: Holy crap, I have wanted alt+3 for so many years.

Answer (score 4):

It also happened to me, I tried every possible key and then I found the solution: press <kbd>F11</kbd>!

Comment: What does pressing that key do? Rather than leave everyone guessing, it's better to post a thorough answer and explain your method and why it works.

Comment: I agree with @Moses , although your solution is correct its not very descriptive and would attract downvotes, specially from people who dont realize that this is a common shortcut for many applications

Comment: @Moses--He can't explain why it works, because he doesn't know why it works. As he said, he tried pressing keys until something happened.  He gave the first useful answer here (note the timestamps), and there's no need to know any more than F11; give him some credit.